# How to create a list with 2 items from one list for each item from another

Tags: logic, powerapps, power-automate, sharepoint-list

I'm trying to use some for loops or something similar in power automate to assign 2 unique audits to each person in a list. I'm not sure how that logic would work.

As an example, the list of audits would be something like audit 1,2,3,4,5,...x and list of people would be person 1,2. The final list would be something like:

```
|Assignment ID | Person   |Audit
| ------------ | -------- |-----
| n            | 1        | 1
| n+1          | 1        | 2
| n+2          | 2        | 3
| n+3          | 2        | 4
```

Any ideas? I've done something like this with an excel macro but now I'm trying to apply it to a power app/ SharePoint list using power automate or code within power apps. (I could use something else but that's what I'm using at the moment)

I tried using some for loops but the list doesn't come out how I want. I'm not sure what type of logic I should use for this.

Comment: Sorry but it's a little unclear to me.  What data are you starting with to do this?  Is it the table you've shown?!?  Show a before **and** an after example if you can.  Far too hard to help at present.

Comment: I have two sharepoint lists and I'm trying to generate a third list. The first sharepoint list for this example would be a 1 column list with people's names (let's say Kevin, Steve). The second list is a name of possible assignments (let's say a,b,c,d,e,f,g...).

I want to make a program which would take those two lists and output a list that looks like:  [(Kevin, a), (Kevin, b), (Steve, c), (Steve, D)]

Comment: So what's the binding lookup that joins the two datasets together?  i.e. how does Steve know he's assigned to C and D and how does Kevin know he's assigned to A and B?

Comment: The output list is what would tell Kevin and Steve what they are assigned to. I want to assign Kevin the first two, then Steve the second two, then person x the third two and so on until there are no more people.